# How to check composer for available versions for possible download and what to type in the terminal

Tags: drupal, composer-php

Trying to download older version of views_bootstrap module via composer. On the https://packagist.org there is no option to check for available versions. From Drupal website you can see there are two versions available: Bootstrap3 and Bootstrap4. v3 is needed. By default v4 is installed

Of course you can manually download v3 however it would be nice to know.

In this example:

It should be something like:

```
composer require drupal/views_bootstrap:8.x-3.x
or
composer require drupal/views_bootstrap:8.x-3.1
```

but it is not working...

also which Composer command would give available Packagist version.

Answer (score 1):

This would be because Drupal is not making their repo publicly available, or at least not through the packagist.

You can find a list of version via the Drupal git page of the module: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views_bootstrap/-/branches

So if you want to have this installed by composer, you will have to edit it into your `composer.json`, along with the right `repositories` to use

Minimum `composer.json` required:

```
{
    "name": "root/app",
    "require": {},
    "repositories": [                          
        {            
            "type": "vcs",
            "url" : "https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views_bootstrap.git"
        }                                                                   
    ]                                                                       
}
```

Then you will be able to require your dependency:

```
$ composer require drupal/views_bootstrap:dev-8.x-3.x
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing drupal/views_bootstrap (dev-8.x-3.x eee11be): Cloning eee11be1b4 from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Mind the `dev-` in front of the version number, that is needed because your source is a repository (see documentation: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#why-aliases-).

Comment: Or try:  composer show --all drupal/module_name and then composer require drupal/field_group (version number)